# How to parse xml file in delphi 7

Tags: xml, parsing, delphi-7, xsd-validation, msxml

Good morning,
I need to validate an XML against its XSD (parsing); I use Delphi 7 on a Win7 Virtualbox machine. I have found examples and explanations in Internet. I have chosen this example that is seemed me simple and proper:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var XML, XSDL: Variant;
begin
  XSDL := CreateOLEObject('MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache.4.0');
  XSDL.validateOnLoad := True;
  XSDL.add('','C:\Lavoro\Fattura_Elettronica_PRIVATI\Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.2.1.xsd');
  ShowMessage('Schema Loaded');
  XML := CreateOLEObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0');
  XML.validateOnParse := True;
  XML.resolveExternals := True;
  XML.schemas := XSDL;
  XML.load(Edit1.Text);
  ShowMessage(XML.parseError.reason);
end;
```

But the "CreateOLEObject" function raise an exception class EOleSysError with message "interface string not valid" (translated by italian). In uses clause I've inserted "OleCtnrs, ComObj, xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, MSXML2_TLB". 
Why this exception?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Use a pure delphi library for xml parsing

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual error code? If it is 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING) the message is "Invalid class string", instead of "Interface string not valid". My guess is that MSXML4 is not installed on your computer. It is old, use MSXML6 instead.

Comment: Perhaps you are reason. Try to install MSXML6. I make to know something.

Comment: Hello, I have installed MSXML6 SP1, iling the same project and the same error appears: "project ControlXml.exe raised exception class EOleSysError with message ""Stinga dell'interfaccia non valida"". Process stopped...". Is it necessary to vary the references to Xml? (where is 4 there are to change in 6)? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to change MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache.4.0 to MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache.6.0.